# How to route R via proxy to download a FTP file?

Tags: r, proxy, ftp

SessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] gridExtra_2.3       gtable_0.2.0        quantmod_0.4-11     TTR_0.23-2
 [5] xts_0.10-0          cowplot_0.9.1       ggplot2_2.2.1       scales_0.5.0
 [9] zoo_1.8-0           data.table_1.10.4-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     lattice_0.20-35  plyr_1.8.4       rlang_0.1.4      curl_3.0
 [6] lazyeval_0.2.1   tools_3.4.1      munsell_0.4.3    compiler_3.4.1   colorspace_1.3-2
[11] tibble_1.3.4

My Proxy servers IP address is xxx.xxx.xx.x:8080, with no username and passwords and I want to download an ftp file which cannot be downloaded from my current place. ftp file has a username and password.
So basically I want to route my ftp file downloading in R via a proxy server. 
Any help would be appreciated.